# image retrieval from directory and session variable issues - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

I have a problem when retrieving the images from a directory on my server, so what the main sequence is: in a page (multiupload.php) I added the input, allowed the image to be previewed and when the user submitted, a new directory with their session id would be created, the images would then be stored in the unique directory and the page would then be directed to (drag.php). The newly loaded page has a canvas with different divs to controls filters that are attached to that canvas. My problem lies with retrieving the image with the specified s_id as a directory name from one page to the other.

**Q: Am i retrieving session variables properly? or using them appropriately?**

This is the necassary snippets from multiupload.php's upload script.

```
<?php
  $dir_id = session_id(md5(uniqid()));
  session_start($dir_id);
  $path = "uploads/";
  $dir = $path.$dir_id;
  $path = $path.$dir_id."/";
  if (file_exists($dir)) {
    system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
  } else {
    mkdir($path);
    chmod($path, 0722);  
  }
  $_SESSION["id"] = $dir_id;
  $_SESSION["directory"] = "/" . $dir;
  $_SESSION["path_name"] = $path;
?>
```

I define the directory, whole path and the id for the directory. I would like to retrieve the id in the next page, but it's not doing it correctly.

and this is the retrieval code from drag.php

```
$realPath = 'uploads/'. echo $_SESSION['id'];

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).$realPath;
while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        echo '<img src="uploads/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
    }
}
```

My end result is that I would like all images to be drawn on the page. For now I would like them to be drawn anywhere aslong as they're visible.

If my question isn't clear, feel free to edit or comment where I should change. If you need more code or information, please let me know.

Comment: Use this line $realPath = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['id']; instead of $realPath = 'uploads/'. echo $_SESSION['id'];

Comment: Good interprettor @ApoorvBambarde .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please modify your code to this code:

```
<?php
  $dir=$_SESSION['id'];
  $realPath = '/uploads/'.$dir;
  $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).$realPath);
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
      if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        echo '<img src="'.$realPath.'/'.$file.'" border="0" width="200" />';
    }
  }
?>
```

I have use this code an I get the o/p like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $dir_id = session_id(md5(uniqid()));
  session_start();
  $path = "uploads/";
  $dir = $path.$dir_id;
  $path = $path.$dir_id."/";
  if (file_exists($dir)) {
      system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
  } else {
    mkdir($path);
    chmod($path, 0722);  
  }
  $_SESSION["id"] = $dir_id;
  $_SESSION["directory"] = "/" . $dir;
  $_SESSION["path_name"] = $path;
?>
```

In any file.php, which u need get session:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $realPath = 'uploads/'.$_SESSION['id'];

  $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).$realPath;
  while($file = readdir($handle)){
      if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
          echo '<img src="uploads/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
      }
  }
?>
```

I advice to you read that: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp when i was started with php 6 years ago - it was rly helpful

Comment: I think this is more so about pointing out you need to call session_start() from any page you want to access session data..

Comment: So and I write "In any file.php, which u need get session:", am i wrong?

Comment: Thats correct, its common practice to include/require a common php file at the top of each page.. something like header.php and have that contain items like session_start(). You are correct, you need to have this called in a script before you can access them

Comment: You mean - advice to OP create something like header-file, which automatically included at any file.php ?

Comment: yes, its easily to maintain a single file vs multiple files.. Same as using the same menu.php file for including a HTML menu system.. makes work light and easy

Answer (score 1):

session_start does not take any argument. It's just to put a cookie and to read the session variables. (exposed in $_SESSION). You have to use session_start() on every pages to be able to read the $_SESSION variables.

Answer (score 1):

this will give only image file from directory using session variable.

```
<?php
  $dir=$_SESSION['id'];
  $realPath = '/uploads/'.$dir;
  $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).$realPath);
    while($file = readdir($handle)){
      if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
      if(fnmatch('*.jpg', $file) || fnmatch('*.png', $file) || fnmatch('*.jpeg', $file)){
            echo '<img src="'.$realPath.'/'.$file.'"/>';
         }
    }
  }
?>
```